# How do I add the style property to an ASP.Net custom date control?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I'm working with an already built ASP.Net custom date control, it seems pretty simple, but I don't know much about building custom controls.

The control is a text box that pops up the ajax toolkit CalendarExtender when clicked.  The html looks like this.

```
<div style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap"> 
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCalender" CssClass="netcontrolstyle" Width="190px" onkeydown="if(event.which || event.keyCode){ if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) return false;}" />
</div>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender 
    runat="server"  
    ID="CalendarExtender1" 
    Format="MM/dd/yyyy" 
    TargetControlID="txtCalender" 
    PopupButtonID="CalenderImage" />
```

You'll notice the hard-coded width on the text box.  How would I go about adding the style property to it so I can do something like this...

```
<uc1:datecontrol runat="server" ID="StartDate" style="width: 75px;"/>
```

I see in the code-behind some things are overriden, like enabled.  I thought I'd do something similar for style.

```
public override bool Enabled
{
    get 
    { 
        return txtCalender.Enabled; 
    }
    set
    {
        txtCalender.Enabled = value;
    }
}
```

Overriding style doesn't seem to work the same way though unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (untested)

```
private string textboxStyle;
public string TextboxStyle
{
    get { return textboxStyle; }
    set { textboxStyle = value;}
}
```

In the control:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCalender" CssClass="netcontrolstyle" Style="<%# TextboxStyle %>"  />
```

In the declaration

```
<uc1:datecontrol runat="server" ID="StartDate" TextboxStyle ="width: 75px;"/>
```